# I Can't access Thomson router

Tags: router

This is my first attempt to connect to a router in my life but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

I have a *Thomson twg870ug* router and when I try to connect to it using Chrome to the IP address **192.168.0.1** all I recieve is **'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'** error.

I have tried to clear all cookies and even reset router (hold reset for about 15 seconds).

*Ipconfig* shows that 192.168.0.1 is my default gateway and when I ping that address everything is going ok.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, +1. Does the same issue persist with another browser?

Comment: I've seen this once with a Belkin router, disabling AdBlock Plus solved it, though I was never sure why.

Comment: Try IE. I've had routers before that were picky about which browsers worked with the web configuration.

Comment: IE gives "This page can’t be displayed" statement. I've tried also firefox on another PC but also with no luck.

Comment: Wireless or Wired?

Comment: Wired. Was trying also wirless on android phone chrome but with the same result

Comment: @user3102664 Please remember to use `@username` to notify a particular user when you reply to a comment. Otherwise we don't know you have replied. If you want to reply to me use `@DavidPostill`

Comment: Was this router provided by your service provider? Or did you purchase it? If provided by your ISP, it is possible they have disabled access to prevent user modification.

Comment: This [site](http://techwelkin.com/how-to-solve-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-problem) suggests that you should delete your cookies and try again. This might not be too helpful because I understand that it is not the same problem but I guess there is no harm in giving it a try. Also here is another [forum](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/37594-42-error-err_too_many_redirects-redirects) that I found which might be helpful to your cause.

Comment: @CharlieRB It was provided by my ISP. You may be right. I will ask them as soon as possible.

Comment: @CharlieRB Yeah, just called them and the problem was there. Thanks a lot for a hint!

Answer (score 1):

A *major* security issue was found in this router model. An exploit can be executed even remotely (`CSRF` type of attack) if router IP is not changed from `192.168.0.1` to a different one. Once triggered, all router settings are reset to factory defaults and router is restarted. The exploit was not fixed by Thomson, so ISPs had to came with solution that doesn't lead to hardware replacement. Part of router configuration is overwritten with data provided by ISP, directly and automatically via cable. In my case (Poland, ISP: Inea) after hard reset, the gateway IP changed from `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.100.1` in first 5 minutes, and once this "ISP specific" configuration was fully loaded - `192.168.random.1`. However I'm not able to open router configuration via this IP anyway. Whenever i need to change some settings (i.e. Wi-Fi password), i have to hard reset my router **without** Internet data cable connected.